# Fetch image in React from Node.js request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, superagent, sendfile

When needed, React asks for an image using Superagent :

```
exports.getImgFromSection=function(id,request){
    request
       .get('/img/'+id)
       .end((error, response) => {
           if (!error && response) {
               console.log(response.file);
           } 
           else {
               console.log('There was an error fetching server', error);
           }
       })
```

}

Node.js answers this way :

```
app.get("/img/:id",function(req, res){ 
   // check if exists and then
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './data/img/'+req.params['id']+'.png'));
});
```

But I don't know how to get the image in React.

`console.log(response.file)` is undefined.

`console.log(response.files[0])` is undefined.

`console.log(response.body)` is null.

`console.log(response)` gives me :

[image: console.log(response)]

How do I get the image in a var ? Thank you.

**SOLUTION :**

In node.js :

```
var img = fs.readFile('./data/imagesUploaded/image.png', function (err, data) {
        var contentType = 'image/png';
        var base64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
        base64='data:image/png;base64,'+base64;
        res.send(base64);
    });
```

React :

```
request
       .get('/img/'+imgID)
       .end((error, response) => {
        if (!error && response) {
            this.setState({img1:response.text})
        } else {
            console.log('There was an error fetching server', error);
        }
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using axios (but it will be similar) this is how I get my images.

```
  const res = await axios.get(`/image/${imageId}`, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  });
  const imgFile = new Blob([res.data]);
  const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imgFile);
```

I think the response type is the important thing here.....but I have node sending it as a stream (as I am retrieving from mongo etc....)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

In node.js :

```
var img = fs.readFile('./data/imagesUploaded/image.png', function (err, data) {
        var contentType = 'image/png';
        var base64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
        base64='data:image/png;base64,'+base64;
        res.send(base64);
    });
```

React :

```
request
       .get('/img/'+imgID)
       .end((error, response) => {
        if (!error && response) {
            this.setState({img1:response.text})
        } else {
            console.log('There was an error fetching server', error);
        }
       })
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Axios package to fetch a POST Request in React.
https://github.com/axios/axios

```
https://github.com/axios/axios
```

you need to send a request to fetch image or post image.
Just an Example.

This is a function in React.

```
 async sendEmail(name,interest,email,phone,message){


          const form = await axios.post('/api/form',{
            name,
            interest,
            email,
            phone,
            message
        })

    }
```

This will send the request to Nodejs here:

```
app.post('/api/form',(req,res)=>{

        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(123);
        const output = `
    <p> You have a  Request</p>
        <h3> Contact Details </h3>
        <ul>
            <li> Name : ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li> Interest : ${req.body.interest}</li>
            <li> Email : ${req.body.email}</li>
            <li> Email : ${req.body.phone}</li>
            <li> Email : ${req.body.message}</li>
        </ul>
    `;
```

This is how Fetch request is also done, but fetching part will be in React Code.

Anyways read the Axios Documentation. it will be having various examples about it.

Comment: Superagent is equivalent to Axios so it won't solve my problem. Furthermore, your example show a form with text data and I need a simple image from Node.js